# Get all group by fields from query

Tags: regex, go

I need to get all `group by` fields from query
https://play.golang.org/p/5h_IExbQb_D

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
query := `SELECT sum(a) as a, count(b) as b, c as c, d as d, e as e
    FROM table
    group by c, d, e order by c`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(group by) ((.)*,?)*`)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.FindAll([]byte(query), -1))

}
```

it returns:

```
["group by c, d, e order by c"]
```

But expected output is

```
["c, d, e"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pattern you make use of 3 capturing groups.

You could use a single capturing group and access that in the code to capture `c, d, e`.

```
\bgroup by (\w+(?:, \w+)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bgroup by` Match group by preceded by a word boundary `\b`
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:, \w+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a space and 1+ word chars.
- `)` Close capturing group

You could extend matching `\w` by using a character class `[\w]` and add what you would allow to match.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aiJE9s/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
group by ((?:\S*,\s)+\S*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0obb68/1)